# How does MSSQL field type map to PHP data type

Tags: php, sql-server, casting, nvarchar

What string does the field type `NVarChar` of MSSQL represent, and how to map this type of string to PHP?

Is `CAST("123" AS NVarChar(50))` equal to PHP's `'123'`?

I tried most methods,
e.g: utf8_encode, mb_convert_encoding, iconv.
But the results with `NVarChar` are always different.

What method should be used in PHP to get the same data as `NVarChar`.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please, share with us your code. It's important to know what are you trying to achieve -  to send or retrieve data to/from SQL Server. Also, which driver do you use to connect to SQL Server (e.g. SQLSRV, PDO_SQLSRV, ODBC, ...). Thanks.

Comment: Zhorov, thank you for your comment. I do not connect to the database. I just got this command and want to implement the same in PHP to output the same string.

Comment: Well, it should be `$statement = "SELECT CAST(N'123' AS NVarChar(50))";` instead of `SELECT CAST("123" AS NVarChar(50))`. In your statement "123" is a column name, not a text literal.

Comment: Ok, I try it. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Zhorov,I tried this. I use MD5 to verify ```CAST(N'123' AS NVarChar(50))``` and PHP's ```'123'``` respectively, but their results are still different.

Comment: It's difficult to reproduce and test with a test case, but if you want to select the `"123"`literal, you may try with `$statement = "SELECT CAST(N'".'"123"'."' AS NVarChar(50))";`. As I said, if possible, include test data in the question. Thanks.

Comment: I confirmed that it is ```N'123'```. But I am not sure if the parameters received by MSSQL's MD5 are the same as PHP's ```'123'```. This is where I am confused.

Comment: Bog standard PHP strings are assumed to be iso-8859-1 encoding unless you're using some other encoding library/solution. In other words the PHP string `'123'` will be the byte sequence `0x31 0x32 0x33`. SQL Server's `N'123'` is UCS-2-LE encoded and produces the byte sequence `0x31 0x00 0x32 0x00 0x33 0x00`. These will produce different hash results.

Comment: Hi AlwaysLearning, thank you very much, I think this is the answer I want. Thanks again!